# How to connect SQLserver 2014 to Laravel app

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

How can I connect my `Laravel` to my `SQL SERVER 2014`?

**TRIED METHODS**

***first***

I tried to use `sqlsvr` in my `.env` and change my `config > database.php` to `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsvr')`.

"*my...*" replace my actual credentials.

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => 'myServerName',
            'port' => '1433',
            'database' => 'myDatabaseName',
            'username' => 'myUserName',
            'password' => 'myPassword',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
```

But it throws an error of:

> Database [sqlsrv] not configured

***second***

I tried some method using `odbc` connection find some package on [GitHub](https://github.com/) but no luck, some have errors and some not supported by Laravel 5+

**OTHER INFO**

I'm using `Larave 6.0.1` and `SQL Server 2014`.

Any help will do.

Comment: so now your using 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv').?

Comment: @metal yes its a typo sorry

Comment: Do you use IIS?

Comment: no I use Microsoft Visual Studio